# CustomListView background issue

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout, background

I make a custom `Listview` with image. My `items.xml` is like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:id="@+id/imgViewLogo"   
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="center">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtViewTitle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgViewLogo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:textColor="#000000">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtViewDescription"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgViewLogo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewTitle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"

        android:textColor="#000000">
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

That's working, when but I touch it and move it my custom list view, it's broken. I think there may be problems with this background `main.xml`:

[image]

My `main.xml` is like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_body"
android:focusable="true"
    >
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/listView1" 
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_body"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:divider="#c0bbbb"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm tired to change other attribute, and it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting

```
android:background="@drawable/gradient_body"
```

in the listview in your main.xml add it in relativeLayout in you items.xml just like this

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dip"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_body"
android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" >
```

Comment: Thanks @Irfan.. The way it worked, but it did not produce the effect "click" (default, click the orange-colored effect)

Comment: just use 
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"

in your listview and it will give you your desired effect

Comment: Yeah.. thats working.. Thanks @Irfan..
But the text is visible if desired effect shows.. any tricks?

Comment: okay here I didn't get your point. Is it that you want text of the list item to disappear the moment you click on it??

Comment: in fact the opposite. if I use your code, the text will disappear. How to keep text does not disappear?

Comment: @Arief Rivai It seems you didn't notice that the gradient_body is also black and your text is also black so it's obvious that text will disappear. either change your text color or use OnItemClickLinstenr on your listview and inside that change the color of text to white or some more visible one and revet it back when unselected. hope it will help you solving your problem